# How to scrape all elements and not only one?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape all the elements from a page (like all the prices) - but only one appears, even though `len(info) = 100`.

Here is my code:

```
r=requests.get('https://www.marionnaud.fr/parfum/parfum-femme/c/P0100?q=%3Arank-desc&page=0&pageSize=100')
page=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(page)
info=soup.find_all('a',class_='ProductInfoAnchor')


for i in range(len(info)):
    marque=info[i].contents[1].contents
    nom=info[i].contents[3].contents

price=soup.find_all('div',class_="price")
for i in range(len(price)):
    prix=price[i].contents[1].contents[1].contents
```

How can I find a solution?

Comment: Is your job to analyze website, try more pageSize=100 -> 300?? or iterate page=1, page=2 etc

Comment: i will do the other page after the problem is that for one page i get only one price, one name ...

Answer (score 0):

To *"pair"* product info with price, you can use [`.find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.marionnaud.fr/parfum/parfum-femme/c/P0100?q=%3Arank-desc&page=0&pageSize=100'

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )

data = []
for product_info in soup.select('.ProductInfoAnchor'):
    brand = product_info.select_one('.brand').get_text(strip=True)
    range_name = product_info.select_one('.range_name').get_text(strip=True)
    product_name = product_info.select_one('.product_name').get_text(strip=True)
    price = product_info.find_next('div', {'class':'price'}).get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
    data.append((brand, range_name, price, product_name))

# print the data:
print('{:<4} {:<30} {:<30} {:<30} {:<30}'.format('No.', 'Brand', 'Range Name', 'Price', 'Product Name'))
for i, row in enumerate(data, 1):
    print('{:<4} {:<30} {:<30} {:<30} {:<30}'.format(i, *row))
```

Prints:

```
No.  Brand                          Range Name                     Price                          Product Name                  
1    DIOR                           J'ADORE                        A partir de 64 €99             Eau de Parfum vaporisateur    
2    Guerlain                       SHALIMAR                       844 €99                        Eau de Parfum Le Flacon aux Abeilles Blanches
3    Guerlain                       LES EAUX                       711 €99                        Eau de Cologne Impériale Le Flacon aux Abeilles Dorées
4    Guerlain                       HEURE BLEUE                    599 €99                        Eau de Toilette Le Flacon aux Abeilles Dorées
5    Guerlain                       L'HEURE BLEUE                  506 €99                        Eau de Toilette               
6    Guerlain                       JARDINS DE BAGATELLE           506 €99                        Eau de Toilette               

...and so on.
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/clara/Desktop/Cours M2/marionnaud.py", line 28, in <module>
    scrap_page(i)
  File "/Users/clara/Desktop/Cours M2/marionnaud.py", line 18, in scrap_page
    price = product_info.find_next('div', {'class':'price'}).get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'